# Text overflow in flexbox child

Tags: css, overflow, flexbox

I have two main sections: `.main` and `.sidebar`.

```
.row { display: flex; }
.main { flex: 1; }
.sidebar { flex: 0 0 20%; }
```

In Chrome everything is fine (1st screenshot). `.sidebar` is 20% width. But in Firefox it expands itself to text width even that I have `overflow: hidden` (2nd screenshot). When I'll give `.latest-list li` `max-width: 0` it shrinks to 20% of width but content disappears (3rd screenshot).

[image: HTML structure]

1. screenshot: [Chrome proper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1uRW.png)
2. screenshot: [Firefox not proper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzWig.png)
3. screenshot: [Firefox half proper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEFUY.png)

## Simplified example

```css
.row { display: flex; }
.main { flex: 1; }
.sidebar { flex: 0 0 20%; }
.sidebar a { overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Possimus corporis doloribus, est consequuntur voluptatibus inventore illum laborum doloremque, quae aliquid magni sequi at? Impedit molestias ipsa veniam nobis iusto, quasi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis sapiente iusto, voluptate ex earum adipisci iste eveniet tenetur maxime tempora! Impedit rem beatae fugit iure adipisci nostrum, commodi et saepe?</div>
  <div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio quas ipsa blanditiis aut, a libero. Architecto delectus eveniet error a nisi officiis reprehenderit laborum porro dolor praesentium. Voluptatem, quaerat, quisquam!</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

On Chrome `.sidebar` is 20% width, on Firefox it takes space for text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try switching the `overflow: hidden` to the parent container.

Instead of this:

```
.sidebar { flex: 0 0 20%; }
.sidebar a { overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; }
```

Try this:

```
.sidebar { flex: 0 0 20%; overflow: hidden; }
.sidebar a { white-space: nowrap; }
```